# What is the format of the range field required to anchor a comment to a given cell?

Tags: google-drive-api

I created a comment inside Google Spreadsheets, and the anchor has a range associated with it as below.

```
    "anchor": "{\"type\":\"range\",\"uid\":0,\"range\":\"uvfa7tonc28c\"}",
```

However, the range scheme doesn't have a description in the API schema:
https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-comments

How does one create a comment using the API and anchor it to a given cell in a spreadsheet similar to comments work inside the app?